# How to publish the message in Google Pubsub using camel route

Tags: apache-camel, google-cloud-pubsub

I have to publish the message, "hello" to pub sub using the camel route.

How the message should be formed in camle before sending it to google pubsub.

Is there any example available.

Regards,
Jagan

Answer (score 0):

In your route, you can set the body using the setBody function:

```
from("direct:a")
.setBody(constant("hello"))
.to("google-pubsub://project-id:destinationName");
```

Answer (score 0):

according to the documentation [Google Pubsub - uri format](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.15.x/google-pubsub-component.html#_uri_format), it comes in the format:

`"google-pubsub://<project>:<topic>".`

Also the body should be of type `byte[]` though String.class works well for me.

I use `.toD` instead of `.to`

That has worked for me.